# What is the PostgreSQL equivalent of Oracle `like lower(q'$%string%$')`

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I am migrating one project from Oracle 11 to PG 12 and have the following oracle code:

```
"... like lower(q'$%" +string + "%$') .... "
```

Could anyone say exact equivalent of this code in PostgreSQL?

Comment: `ilike '%'||string||'%'`

Answer (score 0):

This uses Oracles alternative quoting mechanism -- which seems unnecessary.  I think this is equivalent:

```
like lower('%" + string + "%')
```

That said, you should be passing `string` in as a parameter rather than munging the query string.  That is regardless of database.